# GET запрос JS , страницы отличаются

Tags: javascript, ajax, get, axios

Здравствуйте подскажите почему структура полученной страницы через GET запрос отличается от оригинала.
Выполняю такой код :

```
axios.get('https://www.walmart.com/ip/Doo-Gro-Mega-Thick-Hair-Vitalizer-4-fl-oz/16224519', { responseType: 'document' }).then((res) => {
  const document = res.data;
  const product = document.querySelector('#product-overview');
  const list = product.querySelector('.slider-slide');
  console.log('LIST', list);
  console.log('RES', res.data);
});
```

Он пишет что List null , хотя в оригинале страницы он есть и содержит 6 картинок , в чем проблема может быть?

Comment: Наверное, надо показать html, о котором идет речь.

Comment: вы из браузера это запрашиваете? и не утыкаетесь в cors?

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, разница между страницей в браузере и между документом, запрошенным через обёртки над XHR или fetch, происходит от того, что во втором случае не отрабатывают скрипты. Если содержимое строится скриптами динамически, во втором типе документов его не будет.

Comment: А как же запросить через GET так чтобы получить сразу с отработанными скриптами ?